# TFLearn tutorial example how to convulation network know what we need?

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

Want to ask a question.

I am begin to study the TFLearn and had tested the Titanic data. But I don't understand how the network know about we need that missing survival number in the test data?

What will happen if I add the survival and hide the gender field in the testing data?

```
# change dicaprio and winslet into prepared process data by hard code
# add the survival class back and remove the gender field.
dicaprio = [0., 3.,   19., 0., 0.,  5.0000]
winslet = [1.,1.,  17., 1., 2.,  100.0000]
```

Then I get two number after running the sample.
I don't know what the meaning about the number, 
so I remove the label of the result, it show up like this:

```
DiCaprio Rate: 0.99953
Winslet Rate: 0.92489
```

So, both of them are girls?

Answer (score 0):

The reason we are using Survival separately is that is the target value. We are trying to find out if people would live or die.

Please use the test case from the tflearn tutorial (which represents peoples from titanic movie). The result is showing the probability of survive.

You can also do it with sex. Than it will print probability of being female.

Good luck on your studies.